# How to change postformats source code within theme

Tags: html, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, blogs

I would like to change the Dribble icon within the team post types to a LinkedIn icon. I know I can do this by changing the class to fa-linkedin. The problem is I can't seem to find the source for the team posttype.

When I click appearance > editor and search for fa-dribbble (or fa-drib*) the code is nowhere to be found? I checked within all the php and html files that are there.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

The theme I am using is http://www.enginethemes.com/themes/oneengine/ (free download)

This is my website http://www.suuper.co/. The icon that I mean is visible in this print screen.

[image]

I found this reference but it does not really make me any wiser.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That icon is created with the following:

The grey circle (and is found in the styles.css file):

```
.social-share ul.social li a 
{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #bdc3c7;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

The yellow colour is added with the following (and is found in the custom-css.php file):

```
.social-footer li a:hover i
{
    color:#efd751;
}
```

The shape inside the icon is created with the following (and is found in the font-awesome.min.css):

```
.fa-dribbble:before 
{
    content: "\f17d";
}
```

Changing the value in content should work.

Comment: I changed it to .fa-linkedin:before{content:"\f17d"} instead of .fa-dribbble:before{content:"\f17d"}. The icon does not appear? (circle is grey).Can you explain me how you found this? I am using chrome "inspect element" but can not see this css value anywhere.

Comment: Thanks mate, I got it working. I had to change the "\f17d" to "\f0e1". Did not read your answer properly before.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working sollution. 
Put the following code into your style.css file and you are done.

```
.fa-dribbble:before {
    content: "\f0e1" !important;
}
```